# GWT - Access Server Before Load

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt

I was wondering if there was a relatively simple way to access server-side resources (like the datastore) before a GWT page is served. Obviously I could use an RPC call as soon as the page loads, but I assume that would create two separate requests (one for the page, one for the info), and I'd rather just send the data over with the page so it's guaranteed to be there. Can I do that, or is GWT just not designed for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can certainly load a gwt host page dynamically rather than simply relying on a purely static html page.  Though the context of the following article is built around the concept of logins, it does demonstrate how one might do things like startup the gwt app with a Dictionary containing dynamic elements from the datastore.

https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/articles/dynamic_host_page

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with GWT alone, because GWT generates client-side code. Such code is only  executed *after* the page loads.

What you want should, I think, be achievable on the server side. For example, before returning a response to the request, you could access the resources and embed them in the page (perhaps as JSON). Then, your GWT code can utilise these resources.